# Datepicker element for bootstrap V3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I am trying to implement a date picker in my html page using bootstrap 3.
There are plenty examples for bootstrap 2 and I tried converting one to 3 using [this site](http://kenyontechnology.com/2013/10/08/datepicker-for-bootstrap-with-twitter-bootstrap-3-0/) but it just doesn't work as you can see [here](http://dennismuys.nl/Project/holder.html).

Does anyone here know of an easy to use bootstrap 3 date picker?
Since the picker will only be used once on my site i prefer it to be as lightweight as possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: your site is giving error in console log

Comment: I noticed, but it is in the standard less file isn't it? Does it matter?

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone here know of an easy to use bootstrap 3 date picker?

This one is easy to use but does have a dependency on momentjs so it's not "light":

https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker

Here's a datepicker only that has been updated for version 3, and at first glance doesn't seem to have a dependency on momentjs:

https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: Thanks Kevin, this is helpful.
However I can't get the second example to work, is there some documentation or a working example?
Since the html pages in the _screenshots folder do nothing

Comment: In the README, there's an "Online Demo" link that links here (the working datepicker is at the bottom, not in the gray area): http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox